# Which compressed file formats are efficient with rsync?

Tags: backup, rsync, compression

Every system admin knows that `rsync` is the way to go if you need to do backups of large files, e. g. a database file: since it uses delta compression, it only overwrites blocks that have been modified from the original file to the backup one, avoiding a lot of overhead.

Yet for certain file formats, such as `gzip` and `bzip2`, modifying the file causes the entirety of the blocks to be copied again, since it causes some kind of [butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) in the file structure that modifies it, even when changing just a couple bytes.

So, which compressed file formats are the most `rsync` friendly? Conversely, are there any other formats that must be avoided when time is golden and there is 10K of data that must be backed up?

Answer (score 6):

Did you know that recent versions of `gzip` have an `--rsyncable` option? From the manpage:

> While  compressing,  synchronize  the  output occasionally based on
>   the input.  This increases size by less than 1 percent most cases, but
>   means that the rsync(1) program can take advantage of similarities in
>   the  uncompressed  input  when  syncronizing  two  files compressed
>   with this flag.  gunzip cannot tell the difference between a
>   compressed file created with              this option, and one created
>   without it.

Comment: Be aware that some versions of gzip include the `--rsyncable` flag in `rsync --help` but don't include it in `man rsync`.  Other versions include it in both.

Comment: You probably mean ‘gzip’ there